# passing by reference in __clone

Tags: php, clone, pass-by-reference

In my `__clone` method I'm assigning, by reference, one variable to the other. What I'd expect to happen, after cloning, is that when I change this variable for one object it gets changed in the other object. But that doesn't appear to be happening.

My code:

```
class a {
    var $a;

    function a($var = NULL) {
        if (isset($var)) {
            $this->a = $var;
        }
    }

    function __clone() {
        $temp = new a();
        $temp->a = &$this->a;
        return $temp;
    }
}

$a = new a('test');
$b = clone $a;
$b->a = 'zzz';

echo $a->a;
echo "\r\n";
echo $b->a;
```

The output is this:

```
test
zzz
```

I'd expect it to be this:

```
zzz
zzz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your `__clone` method is called, PHP already copied all the properties by value. After PHP finished cloning your object, your method is called. Therefore any property that you access in that method already is a value copy. The documentation states:

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references.
>
> Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.

You can find this in the second paragraph of [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Although this is not a very beautiful workaround, you could rename your `__clone` method. You could then use that method to clone your object, although this of course is not an actual clone anymore since it does not use the interface for cloning.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken when cloning the the reference is dropped (I think this is an internal mechanism), it`s confusing what you want to achieve because you can simply do:

```
$a = new a('test');
$b = $a;
$b->a = 'zzz';

echo $a->a;
echo "\r\n";
echo $b->a;
```

**Quote**:"...you want to create a new instance of this other object so that the replica has its own separate copy."

**Source:**http://php.net/manual/ro/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 1):

That's because return value of `__clone()` is ignored. You can see that, if you change `$temp->a = &$this->a;` line to `$temp->a = 'CLONED';` and then simply `echo $b->a;`

So you can't change the result object of cloning.